# Scan tool for setting Mariadb 11's Optimizer Weights?

Tags: mariadb

Mariadb 11 has a [new optimizer](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-optimizer-cost-model-from-mariadb-11-0/) that allows for fine tuning different weights/costs. Many of them seem to be related to your hardware speed - eg by default it assumes a mid-level SSD.

I'm wondering if there is any sort of tool that exists (similar to MySQLtuner) thay can scan your system and suggest weights/costs?

If not, any suggestions on how to assess each parameter?

Similarly, perhaps this is something that could be built into Mariadb - just run a command that will optimize the costs for your system?

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB is unlikely to predict when a feature will be delivered.  I applaud their existence, and I applaud that they are editable.  But...

I agree that a scan tool should be written.  But, since it took about 15 years to get around to the simple setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` based on RAM size, I am not holding my breath.

On another side of this discussion, I suggest that most optimizations are insensitive to tuning.  That is, regardless of how fast or slow the disk subsystem is, there is [often] only one reasonable way to evaluate a statement.

The main way to speed up a query is to have a better (often 'composite') `INDEX`.  (I speak from years of experience, as demonstrated by my 137K reputation in Stackoverflow.)

Some optimizations that cannot be solved by the Optimizer Cost Model:

- A `JOIN` with `WHERE` clauses on both tables
- `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` -=- which of two indexes to use

On the positive side, having both Histograms and a Cost model can make *some* inroads into my negative points above.

`OPTIMIZER_DISK_READ_COST` is much larger than all the other tunables.  But how good is the estimate of *how many blocks* need to be read for each proposed query execution plan?

"Time in microseconds to read a 4K block from a disk/SSD. The default is set for a 400MB/second SSD" -- This should be easy to easy to find from the SSD/NVME/whatever manual for your server.  (Keep in mind that there are four 4K SSD reads for one InnoDB block.)

Most of the rest are based on CPU speed.  CPUs have barely increased since the turn of the century; I doubt if tweaking them (away from the defaults) would change the execution plan of any of your queries.

When I analyze without such tunables, I assume all blocks of the desired secondary index are cached in the buffer bool.  Ditto for *non-leaf* nodes of the data (and clustered index).  However, I the leaf node(s) containing rows are not cached.  (This works well for a table that is too big to be cached, but not so big that multiple BTree levels cannot be cached.)

Comment: "I speak from years of experience, as demonstrated by my 137K reputation in Stackoverflow." There's no need to qualify yourself - you're the legend Rick James! Thanks very much for the thorough reply. That makes a lot of sense.I'll focus on good database structure and indexes. Still, have you noticed any meaningful performance improvements in mariadb 11.x vs 10.11?

Comment: @nickc - I'm way behind on experimenting with new features and new versions.  So, alas, no.  (And thanks for the praise.)  When MySQL came out with a "cost model", I was quite critical of it because the end-user could not adjust the settings.  I am pleased that MariaDB has fixed that, plus has a number of other good features.  Still, it is a rare query where it will matter.